# Howto mock a service used in a directive

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

We have the following directive :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    ff.directive('mySwitchUserDirective', mySwitchUserDirective);

    mySwitchUserDirective.$inject = ['SessionService'];

    function mySwitchUserDirective(SessionService) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<img ng-src="{{userImage}}" width="35px" style="border-radius: 50%; max-height: 35px;" />',
            link: linkFunc
        };

        return directive;

        function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.userImage = SessionService.get().authUser.picture;
        }
    }
})();
```

How do I mock the `SessionService` during my test?

```
describe('mySwitchUser', function() {
    var $compile,
    $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it('Replaces my-switch-user element with the appropriate content', function() {
        var element = $compile("<my-switch-user></my-switch-user>")($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(element.html()).toContain("ng-src");
    });
});
```

Currently it throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'authUser' of undefined`, because I didn't mock the `SessionService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SessionService.get` can be mocked with Jasmine spy, if `SessionService` was defined in loaded modules and injected in `beforeEach`:

```
spyOn(SessionService, 'get').and.callFake(() => ({
  authUser: {
    picture: 'wow.jpg'
  }
}));
```

Or the whole service can be mocked by means of ngMock:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', {
  SessionService: {
    get: () => ({
      authUser: {
        picture: 'wow.jpg'
      }
    })
  }
}));
```

When there are a lot of things that should be mocked, it is acceptable to have a module with mocked dependencies instead:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', 'myApp.mocked'));
```