# Test an Angular service with real and mocked dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a service for which I need to use 2 real injected objects and 1 mock.
I've read (and used in another class) this post [Injecting a mock into an AngularJS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773269/injecting-a-mock-into-an-angularjs-service)  how to mock a service dependency, but I can't figure out how to create my service in the unit test when I want the 
`appConfig` and the `sessionStorage` mocked, and to use the real `$resource`

this is my service

```
.factory('accountService',
    [
        'appConfig',
        'sessionStorage',
        '$resource',
        function accountService_init (appConfig, sessionStorage, $resource){

            // some account methods are done on a web endpoint
            var webauthendpoint = appConfig.locations.authEndPoint + ':method';

            // Others are done on the API endpoint
            var Account = $resource(appConfig.locations.api.account, {
                method: '@method'
            });

            //removed code

            return Account;
        }
    ]
);
```

So I've seen code where all the dependencies are mocked (in the  `beforeEach`, with the  `$provide.value` and then after that the object can be injected in the `expect` like this:

```
it('should return value from mock dependency', inject(function (myService) {
      expect(myService.useDependency()).toBe('mockReturnValue');
  }));
```

I've seen (and used ) also the example of a service `questionsPersistenceService` which is dependant of `userPrefilledPersistService`:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_questionsPersistenceService_, _userPrefilledPersistService_) {
        questionsPersistenceService = _questionsPersistenceService_;
        userPrefilledPersistService = _userPrefilledPersistService_;
    }));
```

But how to combine??

EDIT, because my question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question.

@Estus: possible duplicate?? That post is about mocking a service in a directive. In my post I've stated that I DO know how to do that, but that my problem is about how to combine injecting live dependencies and mocking dependencies, in the same test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto mock a service used in a directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096198/howto-mock-a-service-used-in-a-directive)

Comment: @Estus: possible duplicate?? That post is about mocking a service in a directive. In my post I've stated that I DO know how to do that, but that my problem is about how to combine injecting live dependencies and mocking dependencies, in the same test

Comment: The question has similar problem. There are several ways to mock a dependency, and the answer covers them, this suits your case perfectly. There's no need to mock the service with $provide.value, angular.mock.module can do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just combine it.
but it's possible too, that you inject all your dependencies like this:

```
var dep1, dep2, dep3;

beforeEach(inject(function(_dependency1_, _dependecy2_, _dependecy3_){
   dep1 = _dependency1_;
   spyOn(dep1, 'methodYouUseLikeReal').and.callThrough();

   dep2 = _dependecy2_;
   spyOn(dep2, 'otherMethodYouUseTheOriginalCode').and.callThrough();

   dep3 = _dependecy3_;
   spyOn(dep3, 'methodYouLikeToMock').and.respond(
       function() {
            return 'someMockValueOrFunctionality';
       }
   );
}));
```

and then on your testcase:

```
it('returns true expected value for dep1 and dep2 and someMockValueOrFunctionality for dep3', function (){
    var result1 = dep1.methodYouUseLikeReal();
    expect(dep1.methodYouUseLikeReal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result1).toBe('real expected result');

    var result2 = dep2.otherMethodYouUseTheOriginalCode(param);
    expect(dep2.otherMethodYouUseTheOriginalCode).toHaveBeenCalledWith(param);
    expect(dep2.otherMethodYouUseTheOriginalCode).toBe('real result');

    var result3 = dep3.methodYouLikeToMock();
    expect(dep3.methodYouLikeToMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result3).toBe('someMockValueOrFunctionality');
});
```

I hope this will help you.